# Substituir ancora por botão em formulário com cálculo pelo javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
function calc(){
  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  var a = +form.a.value;
  var b = +form.b.value;
  var result = (a+b);
  form.result.value = result;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  A: <input type="number" name="a">
  B: <input type="number" name="b">
  Result: <input type="text" name="result" disabled="">
  <a href="#" onclick="calc();">Calcular</a>
</form>
```

Gostaria de por no lugar da tag `<a>` um `<button>`, mas ao fazer isso a página atualiza logo após o cálculo e o resultado não fica visível.
Aqui na postagem não atualiza depois que clico no botão, mas na minha página local sim.

Comment: Não entendi bem o que quer...

Comment: No lugar da tag `<a>` gostaria de por um `<button>`, mas ao fazer isso a página atualiza logo após o cálculo e o resultado não fica visível.

Comment: Tente a forma como respondi ali. se não der comente...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acredito que se eu entendi bem, é só você colocar um botão  do tipo não submit, para não enviar o form e recarregar a pagina sem você ver o resultado!

```js
function calc(){
 var form = document.getElementById("form");
 var a = +form.a.value;
 var b = +form.b.value;
 var result = (a+b);
 form.result.value = result;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
 A: <input type="number" name="a">
 B: <input type="number" name="b">
 Result: <input type="text" name="result" disabled="">
 <input type="button" onclick="calc();" value="Calcular">
</form>
```

**Vale lembrar** que o operador `+` usado depois do sinal de igualdade, como no caso usado:
`var a = +form.a.value;` 
É utilizado para indicar a entrada de um número positivo, visto que retornar o valor de um input, por padão virá como `String`. Ou seja, se não tivesse o `+`, e simplesmente colocasse `(a+b)`entenderia-se como duas strings, se concatenaria em vez de soma-los.Segue a exemplificação abaixo:

```js
function calc(){
 var form = document.getElementById("form");
 var a = form.a.value;
 var b = form.b.value;
 var result = (a+b);
 form.result.value = result;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
 A: <input type="number" name="a">
 B: <input type="number" name="b">
 Result: <input type="text" name="result" disabled="">
 <input type="button" onclick="calc();" value="Calcular">
</form>
```

**Resumindo:**

```
var  um  =  "1" ; 
var  b  =  um ;      // B = "1": uma string 
var  c  =  + um ;     // C = 1: um número 
var  d  =  - um ;     // d = -1: um número
```

E outra forma de se obter o mesmo resultado, seria "convertendo" o valor vindo do input, usando o eval:

```js
function calc(){
 var form = document.getElementById("form");
 var a = form.a.value;
 var b = form.b.value;
 var result = (eval(a)+eval(b));
 form.result.value = result;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
 A: <input type="number" name="a">
 B: <input type="number" name="b">
 Result: <input type="text" name="result" disabled="">
 <input type="button" onclick="calc();" value="Calcular">
</form>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo! Obrigado!

Comment: Podes juntar uma explicação para o que o `+` faz aqui `+form.a.value`? É um truque prático mas pode deixar muita gente confusa.

Comment: @Sergio, desta forma, consegui exemplificar bem?

Comment: @LocalHost ficou excelente, quase uma resposta nova :) `+1`

Comment: @LaercioLopes, se você utilizasse `parseInt(form.a.value)` você estaria convertendo para um número inteiro, limitado-se a numero inteiros, com `+form.a.value` você pode utilizar números negativos, é só digitar nos inputs `-3` e etc...