# Somar valores de 2 campos, clicar no botão e aparecer o resultado em um terceiro campo

Tags: javascript, funções, front-end

Gostaria de somar os valores informados em dois campos/inputs clicar no botão e a resposta aparecer em outro campo/input. não consigo descobrir o que falta no código abaixo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Examples</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="soma1" maxlength="5"><br><br>
 <input type="text" id="soma2" maxlength="5"><br><br>

 <button id="btn">Resultado</button><br><br>

 <input type="text" id="resultado" maxlength="5">
</body>
</html>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 var soma1 = document.getElementById('soma1');  
 var soma2 = document.getElementById('soma2');
 var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
 var result = document.getElementById('resultado');

 soma1 = parseInt(soma1.value);
 soma2 = parseInt(soma2.value);


 btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
   somatotal();
 });    

 function somatotal(){
  var soma = soma1 + soma2;
    document.getElementById('resultado').value = soma;  
 }

  </script>
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173458/substituir-ancora-por-bot%C3%A3o-em-formul%C3%A1rio-com-c%C3%A1lculo-pelo-javascript

Comment: Na resposta dessa pergunta que passei tem uma informação importante sobre conversão do valor informado no imput.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Laércio!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema é que:

Ao início da aplicação o código a seguir é executado:

```
soma1 = parseInt(soma1.value);
soma2 = parseInt(soma2.value);
```

Atribuindo o valor de `parseInt(vazio)` às variavies.
 Esse valor não é alterado após digitar no campo.

Uma solução é pegar esse valor novamente sempre que o botão for clicado:

```js
 var soma1 = document.getElementById('soma1');  
 var soma2 = document.getElementById('soma2');
 var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
 var result = document.getElementById('resultado');




 btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
   somatotal();
 });    

 function somatotal(){
  var soma1Val = parseInt(soma1.value);
  var soma2Val = parseInt(soma2.value);
  var soma = soma1Val + soma2Val;
    document.getElementById('resultado').value = soma;  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Examples</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="soma1" maxlength="5"><br><br>
 <input type="text" id="soma2" maxlength="5"><br><br>

 <button id="btn">Resultado</button><br><br>

 <input type="text" id="resultado" maxlength="5">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edson obrigado! sua explicação deixou tudo claro! abç